# how to pass "question mark" in url javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angularjs app, i have a url like
 `http://url.com/my_app/#/store/items`. 
Now i want to append query string for example,
 `http://url.com/my_app/#/store/items?page=2`. 
but in url, javascript encodes the `"?" to "%3F"` which i don't want. It should remain "?" only in the url as angularjs $location.search() returns nothing for "%3F".

How it can be done ?

Comment: Check this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

Comment: should the url pattern look like `http://url.com/my_app/#/store/items/page/2` instead of `http://url.com/my_app/#/store/items?page=2`. As it may be more correct to have `/` pattern instead of `?` pattern after the `#`

Comment: no i want to add it in qurystring only.. Its requirement//

Comment: why aren't you using `$location.search('page',2)` to set the query? Or working with routeparams?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

There is not enough details in your question so I will assume that you are using AngularJS routing - or at least the [$location service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location) - in non-HTML5 mode. If so, the part after the `#` character represents your URL from the single-page-application point of view (more about AngularJS [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location)).

If the above assumptions are correct it means that **you shouldn't try to add or manipulate the question mark "by hand"**. Instead you should change the `search` part of the `$location` to manipulate query string (part after `?`) and the question mark will be added / removed to the final URL as needed.

In your case you could write:

```
$location.path('/store/items').search('page', 2)
```

This is assuming that you are manipulating URLs from JavaScript, as stated in your question.

Comment: very nice answer! works very well for me and it a lot cleaner than what i did simply because i did not RTFM :D

Comment: Definitely the correct answer.  Kind of sucks though if you have a prebuilt URL from somewhere else in the app that you now have to parse into 3 values.  Ugh...  that's angular poop.  Owch!

Comment: @Mark if you don't want to split the URL, see my answer.

Comment: Very neat answer! Though simple, would like to mention that you can pass multiple search parameters using object syntax also.However, in that case angular will replace full search object with the provided object.

Answer (score 24):

If you are using the $location service then use `$location.url('/store/items?page=2')` instead. This has been a setter method from at least 1.0.7 and works a treat in my 1.1.5 app.

Comment: Def the best answer if all you have is the url string.

Answer (score 3):

you can create a parameter object like:

```
var param = {
    page: 2
}
$location.url("/store/items").search(param)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the **ui-router** which is highly recommended, you could use `$state.go(to, params, options)` as described [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).

As prerequisite you need to define your state properly, that means every possible query parameter must be made known to the ui-router. See the following example (`page` and `otherParam`):

```
$stateProvider.
state('storeItems', {
  url: '/store/items?page&otherParam',
  templateUrl: '/modules/store/views/item.client.view.html'
});
```

And then you can just switch locations for instance from a controller by calling

```
$scope.gotoItemsPage = function(page) {
  $state.go('storeItems', {
    page: page,
    otherParam: 'Just a show off'
  });
};
```

No fiddling with the encoding needed and highly readable!

Answer (score -2):

You can use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

For example:

```
decodeURIComponent('http://url.com/my_app/#/store/items%3Fpage=2');
// will give you `http://url.com/my_app/#/store/items?page=2`
```

Comment: Do not fiddle with the URL for yourself! In the angular context there are far better ways than that. See the answer of @pkozlowski.opensource or even better use $state.go(to, params, options) where params is an object containing your query params defined in your state and their values unencoded.

Comment: Solved my problem with the returnUrl get param in dotnet core, not related to the question, but thanks for the idea!