# How to use Querystring with $location.path() in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to redirect user to another page after successful login using query string. If I copy & paste to browser's address bar `http://example.com/#/login?ref=/path/to/redirect` it works fine. But if I use

```
$location.path("/login?ref=/path/to/redirect");
```

url looks like

```
http://example.com/#/login%3Fref=/path/to/redirect
```

How can I decode %3F to '?' ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using ui-router? you should be able to do $state.go('state', {ref: 'params'} and pass in the query string.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197837/how-to-pass-question-mark-in-url-javascript

Comment: You can also use `$routeParams` and create a route that looks like this: `/login/:ref` and then `ref` would be a parameter in the `$routeParams` service. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It should be

```
$location.path('/login').search('ref', '/path/to/redirect')
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work if you have reloadOnSearch set to false on the route. Angular considers this a reload since it isn't set simultaneously. I should open and issue in angular.js for this but do you have an alternative to set path and query simultaneously (other than setting the location object directly which would cause a full reload)

Comment: What if you have some common component, that doesn't know anything about query string content? How can you pass it then?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I want to change path and search the same time.

It is possible by doing this:

```
$location.$$search ={foo:'bar', buz:'buz'}
$location.$$path = '/some/path'
$location.$$compose()
```

It is not documented and it could broke at any new angular version.