# AngularJS, how to change query string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example, i have this url: `http://local.com/`. When i called function in my `SearchController` i want set `text=searchtext` and get url like this:
`http://local.com/?text=searchtext`.

How i can do it? I tried `$location.search('text', 'value');` but got this url:

`http://local.com/#?text=searchtext`

```
$scope.searchTracks = function() {

        Search.search.get($scope.params, function(data) {
            /** Set params in query string */
            $location.search('text', $scope.text);
            $location.search('sorted', $scope.sorted);

        });

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24189297/4478897

Answer (score 1):

You also need to specify the path :

```
$location
  .path('/path/to/new/url')
  .search({
    'text': $scope.text,
    'sorted': $scope.sorted
  });
```

And the final url will be something like:

`http://localhost/path/to/new/url?text={{$scope.text}}&sorted={{$scope.sorted}}`

Another way is to set them manually:

```
$location.url('/path/to/new/url?text' + $scope.text + '&sorted=' + $scope.sorted);
```

Comment: hmm. first variant not work, i get like this: `http://site.local/#/new/path?sorted=Relevance`  . it's strange

Comment: @illexial please update your question with the current code you are using, the url you pasted here seems correct

Comment: i tried this and it works, but once you refresh the page it stops working.