# How to pass parameters for $location.path in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On button click I am redirecting to another page using state.go(). the code is

```
$scope.usercal = function(x,y,z){
        $state.go('app.calendar',{employeeName:x,employeeID:y,projectName:z});
}
```

I want to do the same with `$location.path(/url);

But how to pass the parameters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188562/how-to-use-querystring-with-location-path-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

hi to pass Parameters for $location.path you should use $location.search() like this:

```
$location.path('/myURL/').search({param: 'value'});
```

This will lead to

```
/myURL/?param=value
```

Answer (score 0):

We use `ngRoute`, which operates slightly differently than `ui-router`.

`$stateParams` in `ui-router` is converted to `$routeParams`, which can contain values in the same way, and is populated using url's as usual like so:

`some/path/:a/to/dir/:b` results in the params to the resulting page be `{a, b}`.

Answer (score 0):

If your parameters are the part of url (path) only than you can use

```
$location.path('/myURL/'+x+'/'+y);
```

if parameter is query string then go with

```
$location.path('/myURL/').search({employeeName: x});
```