# AngularJS Parameter in redirectTo escaped "?" breaks route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I simply like to redirect to an error page with a parameter. Its gets encoded to `/error%3Ftype=404`.
This breaks the routing. The route never get active. By typing or with location everything works like charm.

```
otherwise(
{
    redirectTo: "/error?type=404"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't manipulate the ? in the url yourself through routing. But rather, you can use the $location service in this manner:

```
$location.path('/error').search('type', 404)
```

Refer to this question for more details:
[how to pass "question mark" in url javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197837/how-to-pass-question-mark-in-url-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
otherwise(
{
    template: " ",
    controller: function($location, $window) {
        $window.location = "/error?type=404";
        return false;
    }
});
```