# How to change url without call state relevant to that url in angular js

Tags: angularjs

How to change url without call state relevant to that url in angular js

Here is my url: http://192.168.1.105:8000/#/red-wine/Argentina?toggle=in-stock

I want to show this url in address bar but filter data by using a function.

Comment: I am on a view where listing of products are shown. Now i want to filter data according to provided filters and also want to change the URL so any one come to site by using that URL not need to set all filters again. Now the issue is as URL get change view loads again.

Is it possible when user will on filter, url change according to that filter but state not get change at place a function get call which will filter data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using ui-router, you can suppress the state reload when changing state:

```
        $state.go('mystate',
            {param1:param1, param2:param2},
            {reload: false, location: 'replace'});
```

For this to work your state must include the `reloadOnSearch` option set to `false`, but if you do that anyone who edits the address bar by hand won't get the state to reload either. I prefer just to toggle that option off manually when updating the address bar:

```
$stateProvider.state('mystate', {
        url: '/?param1&param2',
        templateUrl: 'whatever.html',
        controller: 'WhateverController as whatever',
        reloadOnSearch: true
    })
```

And then you can change the search params with:

```
        $state.$current.self.reloadOnSearch = false;
        $state.go('mystate',
            {param1:param1, param2:param2},
            {reload: false, location: 'replace'});
        $state.$current.self.reloadOnSearch = true;
```

but anyone who edits the parameters, or clicks on a saved link, will still get the page reload as they might expect.

Answer (score 0):

There is enough details in your question, I am assuming that you are asking about parameters accessing in angularjs, If yes, here you will get some solutions.

[how to pass "question mark" in url javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197837/how-to-pass-question-mark-in-url-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, Let me elaborate